# Node Js HTTP response crashes when response length exceeds 16101

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am using Node JS HTTP request. When my response length exceeds 16101 , it truncates my response. And I recieve limited response like this:

```
{"id_user":"133696"},{"id_u
```

This is not a chunked response, its only comes once. I want to recieve the whole response instead of truncated .

My Node version is v0.10.36.

Here is my code:

```
var https   = require('https');
            var querystring = require('querystring');

            postData.format = 'json';
            postData.apikey = 'abcd';

            jsonObject  = querystring.stringify(postData);

            var postheaders = {
                'Content-Type'      : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Content-Length'    : Buffer.byteLength(jsonObject, 'utf8')
            };

            if(callMethod == undefined){
                callMethod = 'POST';
            }

            var optionspost = {
                host    : this.host,
                port    : this.port,                
                path    : this.path,                
                method  : callMethod,
                headers : postheaders
            };

            var reqPost = https.request(optionspost, function(res) {

                res.setEncoding('utf-8');               
                res.on('data', function(responseData) {

                    //---->>> responseData containes truncated response

                    if(callFunction != undefined && callFunction != null && callFunction != ''){

                        callFunction(responseData, relatedData);//****** calling success function ****
                    }
                });
                res.on('end', function() {


                });
            });

            reqPost.write(jsonObject);
            reqPost.end();
            reqPost.on('error', function(e) {
                console.error(e);
            });
```

Comment: It looks like `res.setEncoding('utf-8');` is wrong, the encoding should be `utf8`. Selecting wrong response encoding in your case might lead to this error since the receiver knows the length of data (via `Content-Lenght` header, which you calculate correctly) and so it closes the connection as soon as that amount of data has been received... Your response might be encoded differently due to invalid encoding and thus have different length.

Comment: @RobertRossmann I tried your solution but its still the same.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is expecting the `data` event only once, but Node can fire it more than once. In fact, it can fire it as many times as it damn pleases.:) Every time a `data` event is emitted, another part of the data is provided to you. You know that there is no more data to be consumed when the `end` event is fired - that's where you should process the data and/or call your callbacks.

Since the response is basically a readable stream, have a look at the [`data` event for Readable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data).

Comment: In my case data event is fired only once. Its not in chucks. I have tested that

Comment: It's still wrong - this is not how you should work with streams. How did you test it?